# Problem with words written with other characters

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding

On site I have problem with spamers, who write the url with other characters. Is implemented blacklist of words and url detector. But I have a problem with words writing like that `'.3.' or '.' or '..'` . Probably latin letters are replace by other signs with utf-8 table.

And this is my question:

Is there a library in PHP or way translate other utf-8 chars to normal letters?

For example, when we write this modify url in Chrome browser, the browser 
automatically translate to normal letters.

Answer (score 0):

Why not check the URL for well-known, accepted characters and reject the query if there are others ?

This is fairly easy to write and is more future-proof.